# Openstack Hypervisor Local storage increase size

Tags: storage, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have installed openstack using conjure-up and already setting things up. But when I tried to create a flavor which size is 300GB, I failed to create instancese with it. When I see at the hypervisor local storage, it is only 80GB.

[image: hypervisor ss]

My machine storage is 1TB, so can I upgrade my local storage?